# jmeter - generate jmx file using jmeter api 2.11

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to build a java app that would read some access files and dynamicaly create some load and/or functional test scenarios. I am using the jmeter API 2.11.

The application would run within a CI (jenkins). Now, I have heard of some Jenkins Plugin for jmeter that executes some predefined test and eventually produces a user friendly graphical report, I didn't get that far though. First of all I was able to programm a pretty simple  test with httpSampler and just one thread/loop. I could run it within the application using StandardJMeterEngine functionality configure() & run().

Instead, I would like to generate an output jmx file for each test plan so I could use it as an input for the CI test execution/reporting part.

I have found a class **org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.accesslog.StandardGenerator** that would eventually take over the task. Does anyone had a simmilar task/problem and knows the best approach here? I would really appreciate any answer.
Best Redards
m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide is what you're looking for, it contains link to Jenkins performance plugin and end-to-end instructions on how to invoke existing JMeter test from .jmx file and create a new one using JMeter API.

Comment: I already knew this page. In fact I used their code as a reference to implement a test. What I still do not know is how to export the test to a jmx file programaticaly.

Comment: Perhaps `SaveService.saveTree(tree,new FileOutputStream("mytest.jmx"));` is what you're looking for.